# Vectorize my function with R is not working

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I have this function:

```
fx <- function (x) {
  if (x <= 0) {
    return(-1 * (x**3))
  }
  else if (0 < x && x <= 1) {
    return(x**2)
  }
  else if (x > 1) {
    return(sqrt(x))
  }
}
```

I converted to a vectorize function as:

```
fVectorize <- function(x) {
  result <- ifelse(x <= 0, -1 * (x**3), ifelse(0 < x && x <= 1, x**2, sqrt(x)))
  result
}
```

I tried the following values but doesn't work:

```
fVectorize(c(-2, -4, -5))
fVectorize(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7))
fVectorize(c(3, -4, 0.7))
```

Seems like is only taking the first condition.

Any idea?

Comment: `fVectorize <- Vectorize(fx)` would also work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `&&` to `&`

```r
fVectorize <- function(x) {
  result <- ifelse(x <= 0, -1 * (x**3), ifelse(0 < x & x <= 1, x**2, sqrt(x)))
  result
}
fVectorize(c(-2, -4, -5))
#[1]   8  64 125

fVectorize(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7))
#[1] 0.25 0.09 0.49

fVectorize(c(3, -4, 0.7))
# [1]  1.732051 64.000000  0.490000
```

`&` does element wise operation where as `&&` looks the first element to return a value.