# R How vectorize a function that depends on other observations

Tags: r, vectorization

Hi I have a dataset as follows:

```
set.seed(100)
library(microbenchmark)
City=c("City1","City2","City2","City1","City2","City1","City2","City1")
Business=c("B","A","B","A","C","A","E","F")
SomeNumber=c(35,20,15,19,12,40,36,28)
zz=data.frame(City,Business,SomeNumber)
zz_new=do.call("rbind", replicate(1000,zz, simplify = FALSE))
zz_new$BusinessMax=0 #Initializing final variable of interest at 0
```

I am just duplicating the rows of dataframe zz 1000 times to measure performance later.

I also have a custom function as follows:

```
City1=function(full_data,observation){
  NewSet=full_data[which(full_data$City==observation$City & !full_data$Business==observation$Business),]
  NewSet2=max(NewSet$SomeNumber)
  return(NewSet2)
}
```

What I wish to do is apply the custom function to only those rows of zz_new where City==City1.
I can create a logical object i1 which stores whether a particular row satisfies the condition as follows:

```
i1 <- zz_new[["City"]] == "City1"
```

Next, and this is where I need help with, I write a for loop (which takes up such a long time) as follows:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(zz_new[i1,])){
  zz_new[i1,][i,"BusinessMax"]=City1(full_data=zz_new, observation = zz_new[i1,][i,])
}
zz_new[i1,]
```

The above code provides the correct answer. However, it is extremely slow and inefficient. I run microbenchmark and obtain:

```
microbenchmark(
for (i in 1:nrow(zz_new[i1,])){
  zz_new[i1,][i,"BusinessMax"]=City1(full_data=zz_new, observation = zz_new[i1,][i,])
},times = 5)

      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 4.369269 4.400759 4.433388 4.401734 4.450246 4.54493     5
```

How should I go about vectorizing the function City1? In my actual code, I need to make multiple condition checks in the function City1 (here I have just used used two columns City and Business to subset the data but I need to include several other variables). A lot of the vectorizing codes on SO simply use information from only a given row. Unfortunately in my case, I need to combine information from the given row as well  as the dataset. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

**Description of the funtion City1**:

1st it creates a subset which **keeps** those observations where "City" of the observation provided is the same as the city of the dataset. From this subset, it **removes** those observations where "Business" of the observation is the same as that of the data. For eg. if the "City" and "Business" of observation provided is City1 and A respectively, then the subset will only consider those observations with City == City1 and Business not equal to A.

I also need to create other similar functions for other cities as well. But If someone could help me vectorize City1, I could try to do the same for the other functions.

Edit 2:

As an example, I write an alternate function for City == City2 as follows:

```
City2=function(full_data,observation){
      NewSet=full_data[which(full_data$City==observation$City & full_data$Business==observation$Business),]
      NewSet2=max(NewSet$SomeNumber)-(10*rnorm(1))
      return(NewSet2)
    }
```

In the above function, note that as compared to City1 , I removed the "!" symbol from NewSet and subtract (-10*rnorm) from the value NewSet2.

Next, I run it only for the observations where City == City2.

```
i2 <- zz_new[["City"]] == "City2"

for (i in 1:nrow(zz_new[i2,])){
  zz_new[i2,][i,"BusinessMax"]=City2(full_data=zz_new, observation = zz_new[i2,][i,])
}
```

Comment: You example code doesn't run. Your `City1` function takes 3 arguments named `full_data`, `Player1`, and `Business`. But when you call it in your `for` loop you only give it 2 arguments and the second one is named `observation`. Could you please fix up the example?

Comment: And, likely the answer is "you can't speed it up a lot without changing the `City1` function. If that function isn't vectorized internally, whether you call it in a `for` loop or you `Vectorize()` it (which essentially writes the for loop for you, but it's still there), you will be calling `City1` the same number of times, and each call will eat up the same amount of time. You're not making the newby error of growing an object in your loop, so there's not a lot to optimize *except* the `City1` function.

Comment: My apologies. I made a mistake while copying the code from Rstudios. I have fixed it now. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Comment: @GregorThomas Right. I tried not to grow the objects here. Also I did read Vectorize() was similar to calling a for loop and did not use it. Unfortunately, I am very new in vectorization and could not figure out how to vectorize the City1 function myself.

Comment: Could you describe in words what the goal of `City1` is? I think it could be done much more quickly using `data.table` or `dplyr`, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the objecting. Something like "Only for the `City1` rows, for each business, I want to find the the maximum `SomeNumber` among other businesses." Does that sound right?

Comment: In your last attempt to ask this question, you noted that you have a number of custom functions that you want to apply to the data. Therefore, you don't want to change the individual functions. How do you expect us to provide a generalized answer to implement various unknown functions?

Comment: @IanCampbell ah, thanks for that. I was commenting here and thinking "I really thought OP wasn't interested in modifications to `City1`, but I don't see that mentioned even in the edit history of the question." Didn't realize I was looking at a new version of the Q.

Comment: @GregorThomas I added the description in the original question.

Comment: @IanCampbell I was wrong in writing my previous question. The function City1 is not vectorized. I had something like this in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912424/r-how-to-vectorize-a-function-with-multiple-if-else-conditions . Where I can define a separate subgroup and assign assign a different function to each group. I could add a small eg here for City2 as well if that helps.

Comment: My opinion is that you should reframe your question to instead be about performing one or two of the operations you want based on a join between two `data.table`s. But to be able to help, we need to be able to perform the operation so that we can ensure we get the correct results.

Comment: @IanCampbell I have added an alternate function for City2. Please let me know if this works now. Also let me know how to reframe my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fast version to accomplish what your `for` loop of `City1()` does. It seems like you wanted to do this within each cities, so I did that.

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data table and set key for speed
zzdt = as.data.table(zz_new)
setkey(zzdt, City, Business)

# calculate the max for each business, by city, in City1 only
biz_max = zzdt[, .(BusinessMax = max(SomeNumber)), by = .(City, Business)]
# self-join the max values and filter out where the business match
# to get the max of other businesses within the same city
other_biz_max = 
  biz_max[biz_max, on = .(City), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
    Business != i.Business,
    .(BusinessMax = max(i.BusinessMax)),
    by = .(City, Business)
  ]
# join back to the original data
result = zzdt[other_biz_max]
```

If we want to apply this only to `City == "City1"`, we can filter in the first step and make the final join a full join - the rest remains the same.

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data table and set key for speed
zzdt = as.data.table(zz_new)
setkey(zzdt, City, Business)

# calculate the max for each business in City1
biz_max = zzdt[City == "City1", .(BusinessMax = max(SomeNumber)), by = .(City, Business)]
# self-join the max values and filter out where the business match
# to get the max of other businesses within the same city
other_biz_max = 
  biz_max[biz_max, on = .(City), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
    Business != i.Business,
    .(BusinessMax = max(i.BusinessMax)),
    by = .(City, Business)
  ]
# join back to the original data
result = merge(zzdt, other_biz_max, by = c("City", "Business"), all = TRUE)
```

On my computer, the `data.table` method takes 0.03 seconds, and the method in your question takes 10.28 seconds, for a speed-up of approximately 300x. I included the data.table conversion and key setting in that time, but if you use data.table and with that key, the rest of you code can speed up as well.

Comment: Could you tell me, for the line biz_max, what does the "." before (BusinessMax = max(SomeNumber)) and (City, Business) do?

Comment: `.()` is a function in data.table that let's you use unquoted column names inside it

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Really appreciate all the help.